# Which caching mechanism to use in my spring application in below scenarios

Tags: spring-boot, redis, mariadb, ehcache, hazelcast

We are using Spring boot application with Maria DB database. We are getting data from difference services and storing in our database. And while calling other service we need to fetch data from db (based on mapping) and call the service.
So to avoid database hit, we want to cache all mapping data in cache and use it to retrieve data and call service API.

So our ask is - Add data in Cache when it gets created in database (could add up-to millions records) and remove from cache when status of one of column value is "xyz" (for example) or based on eviction policy.

Should we use in-memory cache using Hazelcast/ehCache or Redis/Couch base?

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Don't build a caching layer until you have demonstrated that you need it.  At that point, you will have information to help you answer you own question.

Comment: @RickJames: Thanks for response. As we need to get almost real time response, we don't want overhead for multiple calls and database hit. So trying to build cache and retrieve data from there for ready use. Please share your thought.

Comment: Is the delay to the cache, especially if an update is in progress, any less than the "multiple calls and db hit"?

Comment: Not delay in cache as such, and to avoid delay too, would want to send update to cache followed by write through in db so that in next read call, it is available in cache.

Comment: So, you are asking about the tradeoff between "sending update to cache" versus "extra db hit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mostly agree with Rick in terms of don't build it until you need it, however it is important these days to think early of where this caching layer would fit later and how to integrate it (for example using interfaces). Adding it into a non-prepared system is always possible but much more expensive (in terms of hours) and complicated.

Ok to the actual question; disclaimer: Hazelcast employee

In general for caching Hazelcast, ehcache, Redis and others are all good candidates. The first question you want to ask yourself though is, "can I hold all necessary records in the memory of a single machine. Especially in terms for ehcache you get replication (all machines hold all information) which means every single node needs to keep them in memory. Depending on the size you want to cache, maybe not optimal. In this case Hazelcast might be the better option as we partition data in a cluster and optimize the access to a single network hop which minimal overhead over network latency.

Second question would be around serialization. Do you want to store information in a highly optimized serialization (which needs code to transform to human readable) or do you want to store as JSON?

Third question is about the number of clients and threads that'll access the data storage. Obviously a local cache like ehcache is always the fastest option, for the tradeoff of lots and lots of memory. Apart from that the most important fact is the treading model the in-memory store uses. It's either multithreaded and nicely scaling or a single-thread concept which becomes a bottleneck when you exhaust this thread. It is to overcome with more processes but it's a workaround to utilize todays systems to the fullest.

In more general terms, each of your mentioned systems would do the job. The best tool however should be selected by a POC / prototype and your real world use case. The important bit is real world, as a single thread behaves amazing under low pressure (obviously way faster) but when exhausted will become a major bottleneck (again obviously delaying responses).

I hope this helps a bit since, at least to me, every answer like "yes we are the best option" would be an immediate no-go for the person who said it.

Comment: Thanks @noctarius for your detailed inputs. To answer your questions, we will be using multiple nodes in application so cached data could be partitioned across nodes. Regarding the data persistence, we would be storing field values in corresponding columns in database and would like to update the cache with added values.
About clients, there will be  thousands of clients accessing the application so multiple threads will be spawned and access the data.

Also, cache could able to hold 15 Million records at some point of time and that's where I started thinking about other options too.

Comment: When a value changes, how do these caches get updated?  Is it "pull through" or something else?  Do you have talk one language to peek into the cache and another language (SQL) to look at the database?  Will the cache and the db be competing for RAM, thereby necessitating an extra machine(s)?

Comment: Cache should be updated "write through". We might create multiple nodes on server and implement cache accordingly. We will configure cache in our java application.

Comment: Also, if we want to delete/evict entry from cache based on attribute value, can it be achieved through configuration? For example I can see different eviction method like LRU, FIFO, random etc. Can it have custom value (conditional based on attribute value)? Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Build InnoDB with the memcached Plugin

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-memcached.html

Comment: Thanks @Rick for info. I will try this.